# Using IO completion ports from multiple Sockets on a limited threadpool in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, udp, io-completion-ports

I am trying to listen for UDP packets from a variety of incoming ports(~20). I would like to dedicate ~3-5 threads to receiving and processing these packets. This seems like an ideal situation for IO completion ports in windows. What I don't understand is how to do the many to fewer mapping of multiple Sockets to check on a smaller set of threads.

The following code creates all of my sockets and begins the async receive operation.

```
for(int ix = 0; ix < 20; ix++)
{
    var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                            SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, ix+6000));
    var e = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
    e.Completed+=OnReceive;
    e.SetBuffer(buffer, ix*1024*1024, 1024*1024);
    socket.ReceiveFromAsync(e);
    _sockets.Add(socket);
}
```

I understand that each OnReceive Message will be called when a packet is received...

```
static void OnReceive(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Received {0} bytes", e.BytesTransfered);
    if(!((Socket)sender).ReceiveFromAsync(e))
        e_Completed(sender, e);
}
```

1. How do I constrain the number of threads running the OnReceive events?
2. What is the best way to prevent a stack overflow in the rare case that the OnReceive method recursively calls itself too many times?

Comment: Looking for the equivalent to CreateIoCompletionPort NumberOfConcurrentThreads parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you mean with threads for receiving and processing. Receiving happens in the background.

Anyway, I would use a BlockingCollection.

OnReceive could look something like this

```
private static BlockingCollection<byte[]> _received = new ...

static void OnReceive(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {
    byte[] data = new byte[e.BytesTransfered];
    Array.Copy(e.buffer, e.Offset, data, 0, e.BytesTransfered);
    _received.Add(data)
    ...
}
```

Then you just use TPL/PLinq to process the received data on requested number of threads.

```
var parallelOptions = new ParalellOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 };
Parallel.ForEach(_received.GetConsumingPartitioner(),
                parallelOptions, 
                data => {
                    // do processing
                    ...
                });
```

Comment: Agreed receiving happens in the background, but the Completion ports call into a thread scheduler already, just wondering how to control that. Not looking to do memory copies to another thread and constrain there as I would lose the benefit of the completion ports.